# Using String.Equals in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string

I am comapring 2 contract IDs, one is sent by the caller, the other is in a file and read into a variable.  I use a string.Equals method to compare the contract IDs.  The contract IDs compare successfully if the number in a contract ID is more than 1 away from the the other for example:

CTSRG0006 & CTSRG0005 = false

However
CTSRG0006 & CTSRG0007 = true

the code I am using for the comparison:

```
    If fileContractID.Equals(calledContractID) Then
        isFileValid = True
    End If
```

Comment: If the strings are different, you will get a `false`. Check that they are indeed different. The chances that you made a coding mistake are much greater than `String.Equals` is wrong.

Comment: This is my output: Still no go:           1.  CTSRG0009
           2.  082411
           3.  0077066
           4.  0077067
           5.  0077068
           6.  0077069
           7.  0077070
           8.  0077071
           9.  0077072
           10.  0077073
           11.  0077074
           12.  0077075
           13.  0077076
           14.  0077077
           15.  0077078
Called Contract ID: CTSRG0007 File Conctract ID: CTSRG0009

Comment: @Sean I'm not sure what you are asking.  Your sample output has 17 string values - which of those are you comparing?  For the code in your question, are you expecting both of your examples to return false?   If would help to show more source code.

Comment: The comparison is Called Contract ID & File Contract ID.   The output in question is after 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comparing strings, then:

```
isFileValid = fileContractID.Equals(calledContractID)
```

...should produce the values you desire. If not, then I would be checking to ensure there are no extra spaces in either of the values, or some other hidden characters.